# Having trouble aligning navigation bar and logo

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble aligning the navigation bar and logo for a site I'm building. I would be able to do it if WordPress wasn't involved, but there are a bunch of classes that my wordpress theme generated that I'm not sure how to work with.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

I'd like to have the logo stay on the left while moving the menu items to the right of the logo. My site is invictus-together.com if you want to check out the site to inspect it.
My php/html is:

```
<div id="page">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'invictus' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
            <a href="invictus-together.com"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/invictus-together-logo-white.png"/></a>
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'invictus' ); ?></button>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                ) );
                ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <div class="login-section">
        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
</div>
```

Also, my current CSS is this:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    align-items:center;
}

#masthead {
    display: float-left;
}

.main-navigation {
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 36px;
}

.main-navigation a{
    color:white;
    margin:5px;
}
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: How is this a "php" / "wordpress" related question?

Comment: There is a very minor amount of php in the question and all of this is for a wordpress site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using grid display, and it worked out pretty well.

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'invictus' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="container-header">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('header'); ?>
        </div><!-- .site branding -->

        <div class="site-logo">
            <a href="https://invictus-together.com"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/site-photos/invictus-together-logo-white.png"/></a>
        </div><!-- .site logo -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'invictus' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu') ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#masthead {
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0px;
} 
.container-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

/*social media*/
.site-branding::after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
}

.site-branding .widget {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.site-branding{
    grid-column:3;
    grid-row:1/2;
    align-self: stretch;
    justify-self:center;
}

/*logo*/
.site-logo {
    margin:20px;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row:1/2;
    align-self: stretch;
    justify-self:center;
}

.site-logo a img {
    margin:0;
}

/* Main Navigation */


.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row:1/2;
  align-self: center;
}

.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:white;
}

.menu-header-menu-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here's what it looks like,all I need to do is change the font:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`#masthead {
    display: float-left;
}`

This is invalid CSS.

```
header a:first-child {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}

header a:first-child img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.main-navigation {
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 36px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-top` from `.main-navigation` and add `display: flex;` to `.site-header`. The logo and navigation will be side-by-side and aligned.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to make the `#masthead` container a flex container in which the (two) child elements (the link wrapping the image and the navigation container)are aligned left and right, by using this CSS:

```
#masthead {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #page a {
            float: left;
        }
        .site-header {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 30px;
        }        
        #masthead {
            display: block;
        }        
        .main-navigation {
            padding-left: 36px;
            display: inline-block;
        }        
        .main-navigation a {
            color: white;
            margin: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'invictus' ); ?>
        </a>
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
            <a href="invictus-together.com"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/invictus-together-logo-white.png"/></a>
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'invictus' ); ?>
                </button>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                ) );
                ?>
            </nav>
            <!-- #site-navigation -->
            <div class="login-section">
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- #masthead -->
    </div>
```